# Cannot implicitly cast type

Tags: c#, list, casting, type-conversion

i have this lines :

```
 private List<Calificaciones_EstudiantesResCalificacion_EstudianteRes> Calif_Est;
  Calificaciones_Est = NotasSeriviceREQ.CONSULTAR_NOTAS(EstudianteReq);
                    /* object[] results = this.Invoke("CONSULTAR_NOTAS", new object[] {
                    Consulta_NotasReq});
                return ((Calificaciones_EstudiantesRes)(results[0]));*/

  Calif_Est = Calificaciones_Est.Calificacion_EstudianteRes; //this line present a mistake i need cast but a new in VS
```

How can cast this code?...
Sorry but i dont speak english.
thanks for your support.

Comment: And what type is `Calificacion_EstudianteRes`?

Comment: What is `Calificacion_EstudianteRes`? What type is it?

Comment: public partial class Calificaciones_EstudiantesRes {
    
    private Calificaciones_EstudiantesResCalificacion_EstudianteRes calificacion_EstudianteResField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public Calificaciones_EstudiantesResCalificacion_EstudianteRes Calificacion_EstudianteRes {
        get {
            return this.calificacion_EstudianteResField;
        }
        set {
            this.calificacion_EstudianteResField = value;
        }
    }
}

Comment: It is better to add this piece of the code to the question. It is hard to read it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

And what type is Calificacion_EstudianteRes?

```
public partial class Calificaciones_EstudiantesRes {
    
    private Calificaciones_EstudiantesResCalificacion_EstudianteRes calificacion_EstudianteResField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public Calificaciones_EstudiantesResCalificacion_EstudianteRes Calificacion_EstudianteRes {
        get {
            return this.calificacion_EstudianteResField;
        }
        set {
            this.calificacion_EstudianteResField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

this line is this :

```
Calificaciones_Est = NotasSeriviceREQ.CONSULTAR_NOTAS(EstudianteReq);
Calif_Est = Calificaciones_Est.Calificacion_EstudianteRes;// this line present a // mistake i need cast but a new in VS
```

Answer (score 0):

I  just need asign a position.

```
Calificaciones_Est = NotasSeriviceREQ.CONSULTAR_NOTAS(EstudianteReq);
Calif_Est = Calificaciones_Est.Calificacion_EstudianteRes;// this line present a // mistake i need cast but a new in VS
```

for

```
Calificaciones_Est = NotasSeriviceREQ.CONSULTAR_NOTAS(EstudianteReq);
Calif_Est[0] = Calificaciones_Est.Calificacion_EstudianteRes;// this line present a // mistake i need cast but a new in VS
```

Thankyou for alls support.